# Fullscreen option in R package leaflet?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

The following code produces a shiny app with (almost) the same output twice. One uses package "rcharts", the other package "leaflet"

The first map has a fullsreen button. Is this available with package leaflet()?

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(leaflet)

runApp(

  ## UI ####
  list(ui = (basicPage(
    headerPanel("tests"),
    mainPanel(
      chartOutput("map1", "leaflet"),
      "some text...",
      leafletOutput('map2')
    )
  )),

  ## server ####
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$map1  <- renderMap({
      map1 <- Leaflet$new()
      map1$fullScreen(TRUE)
      map1$setView(c(39.603609, -8.415081), 10)
      map1
    })

    output$map2 <- renderLeaflet({
      leaflet() %>%
        addTiles() %>%
        setView(lng = -8.415081, lat = 39.603609, zoom = 10)
    })
    }
      ))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

**For future readers**

With the package [`leaflet.extras`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/leaflet.extras/index.html) you can add a full screen control to your map.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addFullscreenControl()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for the Leaflet javascript library called [Leaflet.Control.FullScreen](https://github.com/brunob/leaflet.fullscreen).

However, this plugin hasn't (yet) been implemented in the R version of `leaflet`. I have posted a feature request on the `leaflet` [Github page](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/231), but haven't heard anything back so far.

Comment: I've started a conversation of this in the [Shiny mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/ZYvuRjSMPZk). Hopefully people will participate.

Comment: full screen, search and other options are now available for R through the package leaflet.extras @ https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras